# Does Kotlin inline function unwrap parameters when unused?

Tags: kotlin

I have an inline function like this (simplified):

```
inline fun foo(p1: Any)
{
  if (predicate) bar(p1)
}
```

and, say, calling for parameter p1 is expensive.

```
foo(download())
```

will download be called if predicate fails? completely inlined call would look like this:

```
if (predicate) bar(download()) // download() not called
```

Comment: Yes - absolutely. The runtime will need to run `download` for any side effects and whatnot. If you don't want that to happen just move that after checking your predicate.

Comment: @al3c why so? isn't compiler supposed to "copy & paste" inline function? then download wouldn't be called.

Comment: Your inline function takes an object `p1` that must be evaluated. If you prefer you can pass in a lambda which returns your object if called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inlined code would actually look more like this:

```
val p1: Any = download()
if (predicate) bar(p1)
```

so, yes, the other function is called.

This is no different between inline and non-inline functions. The function you happen to put into the function parameter argument is just a shortcut so you don't have to assign the result to a local variable first. For instance, if this function were *not* inline, this:

```
foo(download())
```

is equivalent to

```
val x = download()
foo(x)
```

The language syntax resolves parameters before evaluating the function. Inlining doesn't change this.

If you want it to avoid calling the function unless necessary, wrap it in a lambda.

```
inline fun foo(p1: () -> Any) {
    if (predicate) bar(p1())
}
```

Usage:

```
foo { download() }
```

or

```
foo(::download)
```

Comment: The need for a lambda also means you can see from the calling code — without looking at the called function — whether the parameter is always evaluated (simple value), or whether it might not be (lambda).  Which is good [if you don't like too many surprises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)!